# Amazon Cloudfront sometimes ignoring http headers from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution  that serves files from AWS S3.

Check the following files:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/kekanto_static/css/site.v70.css

http://s3.amazonaws.com/kekanto_static/css/site.v71.css

If you take a look at the headers, you'll realize that BOTH files contain the entry:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
```

Both are properly gzipped in the S3 bucket as it should be.

But when served from Cloudfront, the content-encoding is not coming:

http://img.kekanto.com/css/site.v70.css

http://img.kekanto.com/css/site.v71.css

Any idea why this is happening?

I also checked the Cloudfront endpoints:

http://d1l2emnu9r9dtc.cloudfront.net/css/site.v70.css

http://d1l2emnu9r9dtc.cloudfront.net/css/site.v71.css

And the problem remains the same.

EDIT:
Looks like after an invalidation everything is working properly again, so you will be unable to test the URIs I've given.

All I can think about is that the S3 bucket makes the file available and a only a while after is that the headers become available, causing sometimes the headers getting skipped.

How can I prevent this? Other than setting my uploading files to sleep for a while before letting my web servers know there's a new version?